# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^ne^{-nx}$ on $[0,\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Prove that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^ne^{-nx}$  is uniform convergent on  $[0,\infty]$,

I have started by considering the two cases $x\geq0,$ and $x \in [-\alpha,0]$ and applying the M-Test,
for $x \geq 0$ I have $\frac{x^n}{e^{nx}}$, but I dont know how to find a series larger than this.

Comment: Note that with $z:=xe^{-x}$, the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n$.

Comment: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big( xe^{-x} \Big)^n $$

Comment: @user123 Don't vandalize your questions (or, more generally, edit them) after you've received answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where $x \in [0,\infty)$ show using calculus that $xe^{-x} \leqslant e^{-1}$ and the M-test is applicable to prove uniform convergence since $x^n e^{nx} \leqslant e^{-n}$.

When $x < 0$ write the general term as $x e^{-nx} = (-1)^n (|x|e^{|x|})^n $ and apply the Dirichlet test for uniform convergence. Since $\sum_{n=1}^m (-1)^n$ is uniformly bounded for all $m$, the series converges uniformly if $(|x|e^{|x|})^n \downarrow 0$ monotonically and uniformly as $n \to \infty$.

If $-\alpha \leqslant x \leqslant 0$, then $|x| e^{|x|} \leqslant \alpha e^{\alpha} < 1$ when $\alpha \in (0,\lambda)$ where $\lambda e^{\lambda} = 1$. This ensures the monotonic and uniform convergence condition of the Dirichlet test and we have uniform convergence of $\sum x^n e^{-nx} = \sum (-1)^n (|x|e^{|x|})^n$ for $-\alpha \leqslant x \leqslant 0$.

Comment: Thank you, (1/e)^n is a geometric series so it converges?, for the other interval can I just do x<0?

Comment: The other case is harder, See hint,

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n$ is uniformly bounded and $(|x|e^{|x|})^n \searrow 0$ when $x$ is in the interval $[-\alpha,0]$

Comment: $\alpha < 1$ from the question, so for  $[-\alpha,0]$ that series is convergent?, because (-1)^n is also bounded

Comment: Do you know the Dirichlet test?

Comment: No I have not seen it

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(x) b_n(x)$ converges uniformly for $x \in D$ if $\sum_{n=1}^m a_n(x)$ is uniformly bounded for all $m$ and $x \in D$ and $b_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$  in a decreasing manner and uniformly for $x \in D$. There is no way to apply the Weierstrass M-test when $x <0$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @user123: You're welcome.  The basic test is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) in Wikipedia although it does not consider the extension to uniform convergence -- but I showed you that.